# How to add android.support.v4.app.ListFragment to activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-cursorloader

I have `MainActivity` with layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the `MainActivity.onCreate()` method I try to add a `ListFragment`:

```
MyFragment themesFragment = new MyFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment2, themesFragment);
        ft.commit();
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Error:(19, 11) error: no suitable method found for add(int,MyFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; MyFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)
```

If I use `android.app.ListFragment` adding succeeds, but I have problem with `CursorLoader`.

What is best way load data from a database into a fragment, while adding and removing from activity by clicking a button?

Comment: give a tag to your fragment and use that.

Comment: Just check that how did you import your `Fragment`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `android.support.v4.ListFragment`, you must use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Your activity must extends `FragmentActivity`